# AJAX form reloads my page :(

Tags: php, ajax

I have a an ajax form that reads the data from my form submit.

I want to make it so when the form is submitted, it shows the response from my php callback. For example, if the user entered in the password, update the table and return something like `echo 'Successfully updated your password';`
I have tried reading different posts / blogs about how to do this but my error keeps occuring. It keeps refreshing the page when I click the save button after entering either the password or the profile picture.

***My HTML Form code*** :

```
<div class="modal fade -dark" id="ben2" data-animate-show="fadeInRight" data-animate-hide="fadeOutRight">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content -padded">
        <div class="modal-body _text-center">
            <form class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myAccount" method="post" action="">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-12 control-label" style="color: white; opacity: 100%;">Username</label>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php foreach($users as $user) { echo $user[1]; } ?>" disabled>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-12 control-label" for="example-email" style="color: white; opacity: 100%;">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input type="email" id="example-email" name="example-email" class="form-control" value="<?php foreach($users as $user) { echo $user[3]; } ?>" disabled>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-12 control-label" style="color: white; opacity: 100%;">New Password</label>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control default my-password required" name="securePassword_Val" id="form-element-colors-info" placeholder="Enter your new password here">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-12 control-label" style="color: white; opacity: 100%;">Profile Pic</label>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input class="form-control default profile-pic required" type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="form-elements-file">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-12 control-label" style="color: white; opacity: 100%;">User Level</label>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $member_config->userLevelValidation($con); ?>" disabled>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="modal-footer _text-center _margin-bottom-none">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button class="btn -dark" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" title="Close Without saving changes"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                    <button class="btn -dark" type="submit" name="SaveUserChanges" title="Save changes to your account"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
            <div id="myAccountResponse"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I have a div id called `myAccountResponse` which I want the callback message to display in.

***My AJAX code is*** :

```
<script>    
//JQuery Script to submit Form
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myAccount").validate({
        submitHandler : function () {
            // your function if, validate is success
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "includes/form_submit.php",
                data : $('#myAccount').serialize(),
                success : function (data) {
                    $('#myAccountResponse').html(data);
                }
                console.log('AJAX ERROR');
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

***My form_submit.php code*** :

```
    //Upload users image to our /uploads directory
    $uploaddir        = 'uploads/';
    $uploadfile       = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
    $save_to_database = ("uploads/" . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $normalPassword   = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["securePassword_Val"]);
    $pwd              = password_hash($normalPassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $username         = $_SESSION["username"];

    //Run a list of checks so they don't have to type in a value if they don't want to change a current certain value

    if(isset($_POST['fileToUpload']) & isset($_POST['securePassword_Val'])) {
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) { echo 'Successfully uploaded image'; } else { die('Could not upload file.<br>Contact the Administrator of the website for more infomration.'); }
        $query = "UPDATE users SET password = '$pwd', profile_picture = '$save_to_database' WHERE username='$username'";
        $success['updatedAll'] = 'Successfully updated your password and profile picture!';
    }
    else if (empty($_POST['fileToUpload'])  & !empty($_POST['securePassword_Val'])) {
        $query = "UPDATE users SET password = '$pwd' WHERE username='$username'";
        $success['updatedPwd'] = 'Successfully updated your password!';
    }
    else if (empty($_POST['securePassword_Val']) & !(empty($_POST['fileToUpload']))) {
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) { echo 'Successfully uploaded image'; } else { die('Could not upload file.<br>Contact the Administrator of the website for more infomration.'); }
        $query = "UPDATE users SET profile_picture = '$save_to_database' WHERE username='$username'";
        $success['updatedPpic'] = 'Successfully updated your profile picture!';
    }
    else if (empty($_POST['securePassword_Val']) & empty($_POST['fileToUpload'])) {
        $errors['etyBoth'] = 'You must enter a value to change!';
    }

    if(count($errors) > 0) {
        if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&  strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
            echo $errors;
            exit;
        }

    } else {
        //Write our success return here
        echo $success;
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die('error');
    }
```

Comment: Any console errors? Are the scripts loaded properly and before the document load?

Comment: I am getting `jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).validate is not a function TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function`

Comment: That just means that you don't have the validate plugin loaded at the point when you're using it.

Answer (score 0):

You should prevent default form handling, for example:

```
<script>    
//JQuery Script to submit Form
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myAccount").validate({
        submitHandler : function () {
            // your code

            return false; // Prevent default form handling
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put `return false;` at the end of your submitHandler, to tell it not to do a normal postback:

```
 submitHandler : function () {
            // your function if, validate is success
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "includes/form_submit.php",
                data : $('#myAccount').serialize(),
                success : function (data) {
                    $('#myAccountResponse').html(data);
                }
            });

            return false; //prevent default postback
        }
```

Also `console.log('AJAX ERROR');` was in the wrong place and probably causing a syntax error if you checked your console. If you want to check for ajax errors, include an "error" callback option as per the jQuery documentation.

Comment: Okay, but using `<button class="btn -dark" type="button" name="SaveUserChanges" title="Save changes to your account"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>` or `<button class="btn -dark" type="submit" name="SaveUserChanges" title="Save changes to your account"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>` ?

Comment: I think you have to use the 2nd one, otherwise jQuery validate won't know you've submitted the form. A type="button" button doesn't cause a form submit event, which the validator is waiting for.

Comment: check your browser console for any other errors. If you have got script errors then none of the validation or ajax will run.

Comment: I am getting `jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).validate is not a function TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function`

Comment: sounds like you didn't actually include the jquery validate plugin file in your page. You should have a `<script` reference somewhere in your page which calls the .js file for jQuery validate. It's a separate plugin, not part of the main jQuery library. Really you should check for console errors as your first step when you encounter problems with JavaScript.

Comment: do you know where I could find these required scripts ?

Comment: er, sorry to be sarcastic, but maybe try on their website? Where did you find the code to use the validation plugin? Surely you checked the documentation of the plugin when you were building your validation code and didn't just rely on some random blog? And really any tutorial you followed should have told you you needed to include the plugin file. https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the page from refreshing, you can attach the event handler to the submit button's onclick event. The button should be given an id and its type should be change from 'submit' to 'button'

Comment: No, I know why. It's because I was loading another js file in my theme that's causing it to not load the AJAX in the default jquery library. I don't think I can use AJAX anymore with this theme.